# how to send data to php server without having to keep reconnect?

Tags: php, sockets

I have a php socket server listening for connections.

I am trying to pass score from php client to the server and the server will tabulate the results.

So far i am trying to pass it in this way: "http://localhost/gameClient.php?score=8"

How do i change the score frequently, without having to keep connecting to the server again and again?

Below is my client codes..

```
<?php 
//parameters to connect to server
$ip = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "8888";
$data = $_GET['score'];
$output = "";

// Create a TCP Stream Socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// Connect to the server.
$result = socket_connect($socket, $ip, $port);

// Write to socket!
socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));

// Read from server
do 
{
  $line =@socket_read($socket,2048);
  echo $line. "\n";
} 
while ($data != "0");

// Close and return.
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: I would look into AJAX for this instead of using sockets, since it's a lot easier to implement.

Comment: What is the source of the updates?

Answer (score 0):

i think `comet` will solve your problem!take a look at this : [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a Java applet or a flash program to create a socket connection to your server. Than these applications will update the website as necessary.